# Pandas Dataframe: convert unique row label into non-unique rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this nested python dictionary,

```
poke_dic = {
      'Basic': {'Fire': ['Cyndaquil', 'Charmander', 'Torchic'],
                'Grass': ['Chikorita', 'Bulbasaur', 'Treecko'],
                'Water': ['Totodile', 'Squirtle', 'Mudkip']},
     'Evo1': {'Fire': ['Quilava', 'Chameleon', 'Combusken'],
              'Grass': ['Bayleef', 'Ivysaur', 'Grovyle'],
              'Water': ['Croconaw', 'Wartortle', 'Marshtomp']},
     'Evo2': {'Fire': ['Typhlosion', 'Charizard', 'Blaziken'],
              'Grass': ['Meganium', 'Venusaur', 'Sceptile'],
              'Water': ['Feraligatr', 'Blastoise', 'Swampert']}
}
```

When I converted it into a dataframe format, it yields this table

```
poke_df = pandas.DataFrame(poke_dic)
poke_df
```

[image]

As we can see, the column labels are the keys for the level-1 dictionary, and the row labels are the keys from the level-2. The data-type for the entry is array. I expect to explode the arrays and create a new row from the row label.

The expected output (first few rows) should be like this

[image]

Is there any command in pandas that allows me to do this? Or I have to manipulate the dictionary in the first place? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Instead of creating a dataframe and manipulating the dataframe, you could start off with the correct dataframe.  The issue here is that I had to use `enumerate` in the comprehension to ensure index uniqueness.  You can reset that level if you'd like.

```
pd.DataFrame({
    evolution: {
        (element, i): poke
        for element, pokes in types.items()
        for i, poke in enumerate(pokes)
    } 
    for evolution, types in poke_dic.items()
})

              Basic       Evo1        Evo2
Fire  0   Cyndaquil    Quilava  Typhlosion
      1  Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard
      2     Torchic  Combusken    Blaziken
Grass 0   Chikorita    Bayleef    Meganium
      1   Bulbasaur    Ivysaur    Venusaur
      2     Treecko    Grovyle    Sceptile
Water 0    Totodile   Croconaw  Feraligatr
      1    Squirtle  Wartortle   Blastoise
      2      Mudkip  Marshtomp    Swampert
```

---

**Option 2**
More comprension but with `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat({
    ev: pd.Series(*zip(*(
        (p, e) for e, t in x.items() for p in t
    ))) for ev, x in poke_dic.items()
}, axis=1)

            Basic       Evo1        Evo2
Fire    Cyndaquil    Quilava  Typhlosion
Fire   Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard
Fire      Torchic  Combusken    Blaziken
Grass   Chikorita    Bayleef    Meganium
Grass   Bulbasaur    Ivysaur    Venusaur
Grass     Treecko    Grovyle    Sceptile
Water    Totodile   Croconaw  Feraligatr
Water    Squirtle  Wartortle   Blastoise
Water      Mudkip  Marshtomp    Swampert
```

---

To get exactly as OP wanted

```
pd.concat({
    ev: pd.Series(*zip(*(
        (p, e) for e, t in x.items() for p in t
    ))) for ev, x in poke_dic.items()
}, axis=1).rename_axis('Type').reset_index()

    Type       Basic       Evo1        Evo2
0   Fire   Cyndaquil    Quilava  Typhlosion
1   Fire  Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard
2   Fire     Torchic  Combusken    Blaziken
3  Grass   Chikorita    Bayleef    Meganium
4  Grass   Bulbasaur    Ivysaur    Venusaur
5  Grass     Treecko    Grovyle    Sceptile
6  Water    Totodile   Croconaw  Feraligatr
7  Water    Squirtle  Wartortle   Blastoise
8  Water      Mudkip  Marshtomp    Swampert
```

---

**Option W/E**
None of these options feel clean, so I keep at it until I feel good about it.

```
pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v) for k, v in poke_dic.items()}).T.stack() \
  .reset_index(1, drop=True).rename_axis('Type').reset_index()

    Type       Basic       Evo1        Evo2
0   Fire   Cyndaquil    Quilava  Typhlosion
1   Fire  Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard
2   Fire     Torchic  Combusken    Blaziken
3  Grass   Chikorita    Bayleef    Meganium
4  Grass   Bulbasaur    Ivysaur    Venusaur
5  Grass     Treecko    Grovyle    Sceptile
6  Water    Totodile   Croconaw  Feraligatr
7  Water    Squirtle  Wartortle   Blastoise
8  Water      Mudkip  Marshtomp    Swampert
```

---

**Option similar to @Wen**

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([
        poke_df.index.repeat(3),
        np.array(poke_df.values.tolist()).transpose(0, 2, 1).reshape(-1, 3),
    ]),
    columns=['Type'] + poke_df.columns.tolist()
)

    Type       Basic       Evo1        Evo2
0   Fire   Cyndaquil    Quilava  Typhlosion
1   Fire  Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard
2   Fire     Torchic  Combusken    Blaziken
3  Grass   Chikorita    Bayleef    Meganium
4  Grass   Bulbasaur    Ivysaur    Venusaur
5  Grass     Treecko    Grovyle    Sceptile
6  Water    Totodile   Croconaw  Feraligatr
7  Water    Squirtle  Wartortle   Blastoise
8  Water      Mudkip  Marshtomp    Swampert
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! In option 2, I should use rename_axis() to give the first column a name, and it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after:

```
(
    poke_df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(pd.Series)
                             .stack()
                             .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)) 
    .rename_axis('Type')
    .reset_index()
)
Out[885]: 
    Type       Basic       Evo1        Evo2
0   Fire   Cyndaquil    Quilava  Typhlosion
1   Fire  Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard
2   Fire     Torchic  Combusken    Blaziken
3  Grass   Chikorita    Bayleef    Meganium
4  Grass   Bulbasaur    Ivysaur    Venusaur
5  Grass     Treecko    Grovyle    Sceptile
6  Water    Totodile   Croconaw  Feraligatr
7  Water    Squirtle  Wartortle   Blastoise
8  Water      Mudkip  Marshtomp    Swampert
```

Comment: This works very nicely, care to elaborate how we need stack() and the first reset_index() ? It's basically the first time I've heard of those. Thanks

Comment: @botengboteng, the stack function converts the df from wide to long format. The first reset_index gets rid of a 2nd level index created in the stack process so that only Type will be kept.

Answer (score 2):

From dataframe construction , should be fast :-)

```
pd.DataFrame(poke_df.sum(0).values.tolist(),columns=poke_df.index.repeat(poke_df.Basic.str.len()),index=poke_df.columns).T
Out[485]: 
            Basic       Evo1        Evo2
Fire    Cyndaquil    Quilava  Typhlosion
Fire   Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard
Fire      Torchic  Combusken    Blaziken
Grass   Chikorita    Bayleef    Meganium
Grass   Bulbasaur    Ivysaur    Venusaur
Grass     Treecko    Grovyle    Sceptile
Water    Totodile   Croconaw  Feraligatr
Water    Squirtle  Wartortle   Blastoise
Water      Mudkip  Marshtomp    Swampert
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm trying to understand it. By the way, in your code, the types (Fire, Grass, Water) are still treated as row labels.

Comment: and i think the orders are incorrect.. the first row should be [Fire,Cyndaquil,Quilava,Typhlosion]

Answer (score 0):

Basic Approach:

Step1: Dictionary to list

```
listv=[]
types=[]
for lp,values in poke_dic.items():
    lsv=list(values.values())
    types.append(list(values.keys()))
    vls=[item for items in lsv for item in items]
    listv.append(vls)
```

Step2: List to Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
dfw=pd.DataFrame(listv).T
dfw.columns=poke_dic.keys()
typekeys=list(map(list, zip(*types)))
typesv=[item for items in typekeys for item in items]
dfw["Types"]=typesv
dfw


    Basic       Evo1        Evo2        Types
0   Cyndaquil   Quilava     Typhlosion  Fire
1   Charmander  Chameleon   Charizard   Fire
2   Torchic     Combusken   Blaziken    Fire
3   Chikorita   Bayleef     Meganium    Grass
4   Bulbasaur   Ivysaur     Venusaur    Grass
5   Treecko     Grovyle     Sceptile    Grass
6   Totodile    Croconaw    Feraligatr  Water
7   Squirtle    Wartortle   Blastoise   Water
8   Mudkip      Marshtomp   Swampert    Water
```